# How to format PHP if statement?

Tags: php

Can anyone tell me what the correct syntax is for the following?

```
<?php if (function_exists('z_taxonomy_image')) : ?>

        <img alt="" src="<?php if (function_exists('z_taxonomy_image_url')) echo z_taxonomy_image_url($child->term_id);?>" />

        <?php else : ?>

        echo '<img alt="'. esc_html( get_the_title() ) .'" src="'. esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/images/blank325_170.png' ) .'">';

        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: This seems obviously to be a PHP question, not a WordPress question. The only thing that makes it WordPress-ish is that it features several WordPress functions. Looking at the code, there seems to be some confusion about how to use function_exists, too. Anyway, the question would be improved substantially in my opinion if it was placed in a specific WordPress context in relation to a clearly stated objective.

Comment: Ok, point taken. Thanks for the constructive criticism.

Comment: Does current code gives error? If it is what is the error?

Answer (score 1):

Just some slight syntax errors in your formatting. This should help:

```
<?php if ( function_exists( 'z_taxonomy_image' ) ) { ?>
    <img alt="" src="<?php if ( function_exists( 'z_taxonomy_image_url' ) ) { echo z_taxonomy_image_url( $child->term_id ); } ?>" />
<?php } else { ?>
    <img alt="<?php esc_html( get_the_title() ) ?>" src="<?php esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/images/blank325_170.png' ) ?>">
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Generaly I take in consideration what I'm doing when formating an if/else statement. There are two ways of approaching it and basically, imho, it has to do with aesthetics and what you are used to. I personaly use both ways in different places.

When I'm working in a php only peace of code I use the if/else like this:

```
if(whatever_function()) {
    echo "do something";
} else {
    echo "do something else";
}
```

However when I'm working in a mixed situation, like when working the loop or something of the such I use this:

```
<?php if(whatever_function()) : ?>
    do something
<?php else : ?>
    do something else
<?php endif; ?>
```

so for php code only bits I use the accolades and for mixed situations I use the `:` .

Your example shows an echo is beeing triggred out of the php tags. That will not work. In ths case I woud do this:

```
<?php if (function_exists('z_taxonomy_image')) : ?>
    <img alt="" src="<?php if (function_exists('z_taxonomy_image_url')) echo z_taxonomy_image_url($child->term_id);?>" />
<?php else : ?>
    <img alt="'. esc_html( get_the_title() ) .'" src="'. esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/images/blank325_170.png' ) .'"_
<?php endif; ?>
```